# Python schedule package - can't seem to overwrite a schedule, only add to it?

Tags: python, scheduling, schedule, job-scheduling

I have recently come across the method of scheduling python scripts within the script using the schedule package.

I've followed a tutorial online and tested out setting my own schedule - just a simple print('testing scheduler')

```
def printing():
    print('testing scheduler')
```

I then set a schedule for this function to run every second

```
schedule.every().second.do(printing)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    tm.sleep(1)
```

this works fine, however, if I were then to amend this to print every 5 seconds

```
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(printing)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    tm.sleep(1)
```

the schedule wont just run every 5 seconds, it will run every second, and then twice on every 5th second.

I can see the guy in the tutorial amending his schedule and not having the same problem - does anyone know why mine is doing this?

for reference, the tutorial is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDPQfj4bZY8